# Intellij - Move database console editor to database console below

Tags: intellij-idea

I want to have the editor itself below for easy access. I've tried dragging it below, moving it on another window but still no good. Is this a limitation for view control?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the database console editor is a normal editor tab and can't be placed anywhere else except with the other editor tabs.

Perhaps if you right click the database console editor tab and choose "Move Down" (which splits the editor screen horizontally) you will get closer to the layout you desire?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you want to be able to use IntelliJ IDEA's database console mode, but with the "output" of commands on top, and the "commands" (which is shown as another editor tab) below them. While the editor tabs stay in the "middle" of the IDE and can't really be moved (beyond splitting the window to be able to see multiple editor tabs at once), the "Database Console" tool window can be moved.

Right-click on the "Database Console" tab, choose "Move to", and then "Top". It will then be docked at the top, above the editor tabs.

[image: Screenshot of choosing "Move to"/"Top" on "Database Console" tab]